# Paypal Adaptive Payments Cross Border Fee Calculation

Tags: paypal

How does Paypal calculate the cross border fees to apply to each receiver in case of a chained payment done with the Adaptive Payment API?

I'm interested in Scenario 8 from this link https://www.x.com/devzone/articles/adaptive-payment-fee-calculation-analysis

In my case I'd like to assume that the primary receiver is based in the US, while the sender and first receiver are based in the UK.

Does Paypal charge the 1% cross border fee only from sender to the primary receiver or does it also charge the 1% cross border fee from primary receiver to Receiver 1?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about PayPal's fees and policy, not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

View the Chained Payment as separate transactions. PayPal will only charge a cross border fee if the sender and primary receiver are in different countries or if the primary and secondary receivers are in different countries.

No cross border fee charged:

Sender and primary same country
Primary and secondary receiver same country

Cross border fee charged:

Sender and primary receiver are in different countries & secondary same country as primary. Cross boarder fee charged to primary and not secondary receiver.

Sender and primary are in same country & secondary is not. Cross boarder fee is charged to secondary receiver only

Sender,  primary and secondary receivers are in different countries. Cross boarder fee is charged to primary and secondary receivers.